# AngularJS $route nav highlighting not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular $route for nav highlighting, but the highlighting does not show. Here is the code for the navigation...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myController" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'home'}"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'audio'}"><a href="audio">Audio</a></li> 
    <li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'bio'}"><a href="bio">Artist Bio</a></li> 
    <li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'contact'}"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the AngularJS controller with $route...

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope,$http, $route) {
  $http.post('myform.php')
     .then(function successCallback(response){
        $scope.detail = response.data;
        if($scope.detail){
          console.log("success");
        } else{
          console.log("no data");
        }
     }, function errorCallback(response) { 
        console.log("error");
     });
  $scope.$route = $route; 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the js library?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Did you inject ngRoute into your angular module?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to include it in angular.module